# Preg_match a string containing key value pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need a regular expression for PHP's `preg_match` that can process something along the lines of:

```
variable1=true&variable2=1,2,3&variable3="test"&variable4!=true&variable5!=4,5,6&variable!="test"
```

I would change to just something like json but this wouldn't support the backwards compatibility I need, any suggestions, the closest I got was something like:

```
/((\w+)(=|!=)("\w+"|true|false|\d+)*)/
```

Which is partly successful, any help would be great.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using string functions

```
$string = 'variable1=true&variable2=1,2,3&variable3="test"&variable4!=true&variable5!=4,5,6&variable!="test"';
$pairs = explode('&', $string);
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    if (strstr($pair, '!=')) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('!=', $pair);
    } else {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
    }
    $values[$key] = $value;
}
```

[<sup>View the output on *codepad*</sup>](http://codepad.org/p7sgh933)

This code first splits the string using `&`, so into key-value pairs.
After that, it loops through each pair and tries to split it again, first using `!=`, and if that fails, using `=`.

---

#### Using regex

```
preg_match_all('/((\w+)(=|!=)("\w+"|true|false|[\d\,]+)*)/', $string, $matches);
```

I added the brackets `[...]` around `\d` and an escaped comma `\,`.

Comment: There is no need to work hard when there's a [built-in](http://php.net/parse_str) for that...

Comment: I just commented on your answer, that probably doesn't work with `!=`, since it isn't part of a normal query string.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a built-in function [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str), exactly for this purpose.
There is no need for regex here.

Comment: I don't think (though I'm not 100% sure) this would work with `!=` as well.

Comment: the exclamation mark simply appears as last char of variable name in this case - which can be tested later on